# DataGridView Deleting/Updating problems

Tags: c#, function, datagridview, runtime-error

So, I've been doing some practice code for a few days. I'm working on using a DataGridView, without a database. Everything seems to work, save for one problem. Whenever I click the delete or update button without selecting a record, the form crashes. Here's the update function:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvProfiles.SelectedCells == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No record was selected to update.");
        }

        else {
            for (int row = 0; row < dgvProfiles.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < dgvProfiles.Columns.Count; col++)
                {
                    if (dgvProfiles.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value != null &&
                      dgvProfiles.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.Equals(txtEmail.Text.Trim()))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Duplicate email was entered.");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            DataGridViewRow newDataRow = dgvProfiles.Rows[indexRow];
            newDataRow.Cells[0].Value = txtFirstName.Text;
            newDataRow.Cells[1].Value = txtLastName.Text;
            newDataRow.Cells[2].Value = txtPhone.Text;
            newDataRow.Cells[3].Value = txtEmail.Text;
            newDataRow.Cells[4].Value = txtCity.Text;
            newDataRow.Cells[5].Value = cbxState.Text;
            newDataRow.Cells[6].Value = txtZip.Text;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what you want to achieve? You want check if any row selected or what?

Comment: I'm making something like this, but with a few extra functions, text boxes, etc. Wouldn't it be good to provide feedback when you click a button, but nothing happens?

http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-QQdixXA53Ss/UyiZTH_FSqI/AAAAAAAAAho/7y8kxTeDwDg/s1600/DataGridView+in+c%23+form+2.PNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectedCells` is a collection the system provides.

It is never null.

It can be emtpy though, so if (for some reason) you want to check you can write :

```
if (dgvProfiles.SelectedCells.Count <= 0)..
```

or

```
if (dgvProfiles.SelectedRows.Count <= 0)..
```

I'm not sure why you demand a row or cell to be selected in the first place, though. Shouldn't saving always work..?

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I just thought it would be good for if you don't select anything, click a button, and nothing happens. Shouldn't there be feedback? I'm making a form like this. http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-QQdixXA53Ss/UyiZTH_FSqI/AAAAAAAAAho/7y8kxTeDwDg/s1600/DataGridView+in+c%23+form+2.PNG

Comment: Yeah, well after seeing the image I can understand it a bit better. Usually in place editing is used, but for some cases the 'form' approach is also useful. But then you need a tight connection between the selection and the field contents. Use the SelectionChanged to load the current selection or to clear the fields when nothing is selected. You can also disable some buttons then. This prevents to whole situation.. also set multiselect to false.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm going to try to implement all the stuff you mention.